# How do I check my css file for browser compatibility?

Tags: css, cross-browser

Is there a way (other than trial and error) to find out if I'm using stuff in my CSS that will not be supported on some browsers?

e.g. I just found out that `calc()` doesn't work on safari and IOS browsers.

Comment: best way will be -> http://caniuse.com/

Comment: The best know solution is https://modernizr.com/

Comment: [**calc**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) works fine in Safari and IOS.

Comment: There is something fishy called versions